# How to host an internal website on IIS6

Tags: iis-6

We are already hosting one website on the server and want to host another one that is LOCAL only ie(192.X.XX.XXX/Website) how do we need to set up IIS to handle this?  The local site does not need to be seen from the outside world, only those on our direct network.

Answer (score 0):

You set up the site, and bind it to your internal adapter/IP address.  As in [this unnecessarily-pink screenshot](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12890_01/ales/docs32/installssms/wwimages/IIS_web_site_window.gif), simply set the "IP Address" under Properties for that particular site to be the internal IP address of the server.

Comment: I have done that and it is still not working, when I go to the ip address I am directed to the default website, which is correct.  When I go to the IP/Website I get a page can not be found error.  The website that is the default website is not the website that needs to be internal

Comment: Does the web server have two different IPs, one for the original and one for the new internal sites?

Comment: 404 indicates it's simply not finding whatever file it is you're looking for.  You should debug what file it's trying to load.  Start by creating a file named "foo.html" and going directly to that (as opposed to trying to use default.htm or similar).  Debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

If it works using the IP address but not using the computer name or a domain name then you need to configure the website to use the correct [host headers](http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2005/12/06/Configure-IIS-6.0-Host-Headers.aspx). The host headers are what will direct http://mywebsite/ or http://mywebsite.com/ to the correct website. Alternatively you would have to make sure that that website is the only one listening on the private IP address (IE: make sure no other website is listening on "all available" IPs).